# Partitioning in Spark a query from PostgreSQL (JDBC)

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark

I am running spark (with pyspark) in cluster mode and reading data from RDBMS via JDBC.
I read informations by query (not directly a table)

I use options to partition like numPartitions, upperBound, etc...

```
sql = (select ... )
```

and

```
df=spark
.read
.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=sql, 
properties=connectionProperties, column="brand_id", lowerBound=1, 
upperBound=12000,numPartitions=10000 )
```

Unfortunately Spark transform partitions options on WHERE clause at the end of query generated, so PostGreSQL read full table full without use index !

I have got one queries like that

```
SELECT "brand_id","brand_name","eq_ref_raw","oe","btimestamp" FROM 
  ( select  ... ) 
tab WHERE brand_id >= 5 AND brand_id < 6
```

Answer (score 0):

What you try to do seems impossible in current Spark's version. The executed query is constructed as that:

```
   val sqlText = s"SELECT $columnList FROM ${options.table} $myWhereClause"
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlText,
        ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)
```

(see org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD#compute)

`options.table` corresponds to (SELECT ...) statement from `table` attribute.

Could you explain why do you need to load the columns from a subquery ? If you make joins or other SQL operations inside this subquery, you can always "workaround" that and use Spark SQL to do that (joins, SQL operations and so on).

---

edit:

As you explained, the reason of your subquery use is JSONB extract. Evidently, it'll perform better as SQL native operation but if you want to use Spark to parallelize your processing, IMO you'll need to declare your JSON processing at Spark level, as here:

```
CREATE TABLE jsonb_test (
  content jsonb
);

INSERT INTO jsonb_test (content) VALUES 
('{"first_name": "X", "last_name": "Y"}');
```

And the code going with:

```
val opts = Map("url" -> "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/spark_jsonb_test",
  "dbtable" -> "jsonb_test", "user" -> "root", "password" -> "root",
  "driver" -> "org.postgresql.Driver")
val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("first_name", StringType, true), StructField("last_name", StringType, true)
))
import sparkSession.implicits._
val personDataFrame = sparkSession.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .options(opts)
  .load()
  .withColumn("person", functions.from_json($"content", schema))

val extractedJsonNames = personDataFrame.collect.map(row => row.get(1).toString)

extractedJsonNames should have size 1
extractedJsonNames(0) shouldEqual "[X,Y]"
```

Spark supports JSONB fields throughout `PostgresDialect` that in its method converting DB types to Catalyst types considers JSONB as a `StringType`:

```
  private def toCatalystType(
  typeName: String,
  precision: Int,
  scale: Int): Option[DataType] = typeName match {
      case "bool" => Some(BooleanType)
      case "bit" => Some(BinaryType)
      case "int2" => Some(ShortType)
      case "int4" => Some(IntegerType)
      case "int8" | "oid" => Some(LongType)
      case "float4" => Some(FloatType)
      case "money" | "float8" => Some(DoubleType)
      case "text" | "varchar" | "char" | "cidr" | "inet" | "json" | "jsonb" | "uuid" =>
        Some(StringType)
```

Comment: I use query because I need to get some field from a jsonb column without get it entirely.

Comment: OK, thanks for your clarification. I added some snippet showing that it's possible to extract data from JSONB columns as well. That's true that the column will be retrieved from the database entirely but I don't see how it could be feasible differently. But if you can share here what did you do to solve the issue, it would be great. Thanks !